# How to make a query based on a view?

Tags: phalcon

The standard way to make a query against a database `table` is to create a `model` and create a function within it , for example :

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query;

class Client extends Model {

    function lireParCritere($critere) {

        $sSQL = "
                SELECT c.clt_id as clt_id,c.clt_cin_pass,c.clt_nom,c.clt_prenom,c.clt_tel,
                c.clt_adresse,c.clt_comment,CONCAT_WS(
                                                        ' ',
                                                        c.clt_nom,
                                                        c.clt_prenom
                                                    ) AS noms 
                FROM Client as c WHERE 1 = 1 ";

        if(isset($critere["clt_id"]) && $critere["clt_id"] != "") {
            $sSQL .= "AND c.clt_id = '" . $critere["clt_id"] . "' ";    
        }

        $sSQL .= " ORDER BY noms";

        $query = new Query($sSQL,$this->getDI());

        $ret = $query->execute();

        return $ret;

    }
}

?>
```

What is the way to make a query against a database `view` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database view is basically the output of a SQL query stored in another table. You can think of a view as an alias for a specific SQL query that you can then run other queries on top of. (kind of like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_one, table_two, table_n);`)

This means that you can treat the view as a regular table and pull from it without any issues.

So lets say you have a database view that has three columns `id`, `col_one`, `col_two`. You could do something similar to the following.

```
<?php

/**
 * Model representing the database view
 */
class Example extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public $id;

    public $col_one;

    public $col_two;

    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'view_name_in_database';
    }

    public function columnMap()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'id',
            'col_one' => 'col_one',
            'col_two' => 'col_two'
        );
    }

}

// example query on the model
$examples = Example::query()
    ->where('id = :id:')
    ->bind(array(
        'id' => 55
    ))->execute();

?>
```